# FormView change data before inserting to sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using FormView to add new data to the sql server.
I try to change some of the data that the user inserting, like replace "a" with "A"

I try to use the following code:

```
protected void FormViewInsertEventHandler(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Values["Institution_fax"] = "33333";
}
```

and

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSP" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
  InsertCommand="usp_limodimInstitution_insert" 
  InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
  SelectCommand="select * from tbl_limodim_Institution">
```

But i get the following error

> No overload for 'FormViewInsertEventHandler' matches delegate
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewInsertEventHandler'

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature is incorrect for the event handler, it should be:

```
protected void FormViewInsertEventHandler(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Values["Institution_fax"] = "33333";
}
```

You can't replace the FormViewInsertEventArgs with SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument to the event handler is incorrect

```
protected void FormViewInsertEventHandler(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
```

should be:

```
protected void FormViewInsertEventHandler(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change signature of your delegate to

```
public delegate void FormViewInsertEventHandler( Object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e )
{
   ......
}
```